# :Active HTML/CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css

Somethings wrong with :active, if anyone can find the problem it would be appreciated.

Html Code : http://pastebin.com/4wCi3L2Z

CSS Code : http://pastebin.com/jZvgdDaA

Thanks.

Comment: You want to address `.active` (that's a single dot). By the way, this question is not very well asked. You should state at least, what you think the exact problem is, and what you already did to try to fix it. As a base line, try to make the answerers' lifes as easy a possible with the question.

Comment: Please include the relevant code here instead of linking to an external site. If the external site changes or goes away, this question then loses context and becomes useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html has a `class="active"` but your css is using the :active selector which is different than a class. You may want to just use the :active selector or else use the class selector `.active` in your css. I think you may be confusing the two.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Worked! <3

Comment: @CameronHowson Please mark answer as accepted if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

The **:active** selector is before the main (which defines the default style).

The right would be like this (in this order):

```
#nav li a {... }
#nav li a:hover {...}
#nav li a:active {...}
```

I recommend using **:focus** too:

```
#nav li a {... }
#nav li a:hover {...}
#nav li a:active, #nav li a:focus {...}
```

Now if you want o focus remains after changing the focus to another object, you have to use **javascript** (**Jquery**, **Mootools** or **Dojo.js** should solve your problem).

I recommend using javascript and className.

Another thing about **CSS**, never do so:

```
#myID p em{...} 
#myID em.myClass{...}
```

The correct procedure is as follows:

```
#myID p em{...} 
#myID p em.myClass{...}
```